# Cartesian product of countable number of finite sets is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Cartesian product of countable number of finite sets is countable. True or false?

I think this statement is false. Because consider
$A = \{1,0\}$ . If we compute countable product of $A$ with itself, i.e, $A \times A \times \dots $ then it contains every sequence consists of 0 and 1, which is uncountable. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right, except that, when you wrote $A\times A\times\cdots\times A$, you should have written just $A\times A\times\cdots$. Yes, this is the set of all sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s, which is uncountable.

Comment: thank you. I edited it.